# Do night driving glasses make it easier to see at night?

Tags: ophthalmology, driving

There are many yellow-tinted driving glasses being sold with claims like [this one](https://www.eschenbach.com/images/Haven%20Night%20Driver%20Brochure.pdf):

> - Yellow lens tint enhances contrast at night
> - Anti-reflective coating reduces glare.

There are also many posts like this questioning the effectiveness of them

[Night Driving Glasses May Hurt, Not Help](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/tips-prevention/night-driving-glasses-may-hurt-not-help)

> But do night driving glasses work? Ophthalmologist Andrew Iwach, MD, isn't so certain. He discusses his doubts in this ABC news segment.
>
> What concerns Dr. Iwach is that the tinted or polarized lenses used on so-called night vision glasses are designed to limit or reduce the amount of light getting to the eye. Anything that does this at night will actually make it harder to see, not easier, according to Dr. Iwach.

Do night time driving glasses make it easier to see at night?

Comment: I presume the theory behind the glasses is that they increase contrast at the expense of color range. It makes sense theoretically, but does it actually increase contrast? I've always thought not, so great question.

Comment: The idea behin night glasses is that in night, the contrast between colors recievied by your eyes is totaly different and some lights can flash you while what you want to see appear to be too dark. So theses glasses rebalances colors and use polarisation to reduce flashing lights and allow you to see darker things. But indon't know if it's realy working, but it's clear his argument is biaised.

Comment: "100% UVA/UVB" Lol, blocks 100% of something that isn't there.

Comment: Anyways, the only way I could see a benefit from wearing special glasses while driving at night is if they partially filter the head lights of other cars (so you don't get dazed and lose night vision).

Comment: Other than personal anecdote, I have no more evidence than anyone else. However, I think all the descriptions of how these things are supposed to work (including Dr. Iwach) are far off the mark. These glasses are specifically intended to remove only a narrow slice at the far blue end of the visible spectrum: a region which is both worse for causing glare, and much stronger from the new HID head lights. And personal anecdotal evidence: they make very little difference with halogen lamps, but they *dramatically* reduce glare from HID lamps. In fact HID lamps fade out to a dull greenish glow.

Comment: The human eye does not focus well on blue light.  Blue lights appear out of focus and it is difficult to tell how near or far away they are.  (e.g. The office where I once worked had a digital clock with blue digits.  A few people had no problem, but many of us couldn't tell what time it was unless we were standing very close to it.) ¶ These night glasses filter out the blue light, so everything you see *is* in focus. They definitely make things appear clearer and make driving a more comfortable experience.

Comment: @PyRulez I did get prescribed yellow-tinted glasses by my ophthalmologist for dazzle issues, but I'm not sure if the specs on my glasses match shelf-standard night vision glasses. It did help immensely for driving in poorly-lit roads

Answer (score 8):

Personal test experiment, (more of an extended comment than an answer)...

Sometimes I have to drive a four door sedan at night, during times of sporadic traffic, in a town with curvy roads and hills where about half the cars on the road are SUVs, and half of those never seem to turn off their hi-beams.  SUVs are taller than sedans and have headlights at about the same level as both the front windshield and rear window of the sedan:  the resulting glare is more severe than if all the other cars were sedans of the same height.  On a straight road the oncoming hi-beams needn't be so blinding, (one can look to the right), but on a curve with an oncoming caravan of hi-beams, (or worse, a curve on the top of a hill), looking to the right means the lights from the cars in back of the first oncoming car will still get you.

Until recently I've been using the squint method to cope with the above conditions, which is to squint the left eye closed when there's oncoming traffic, using the bridge of the nose as shade to one's open right eye which accommodates itself to the glare.  When the oncoming traffic ceases and the right eye has momentarily lost its [night vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotopic_vision), (a few dangerous seconds of blindness), open the left eye, which still
has its night vision.  This method works, but it's stressful, and it feels like a huge relief when the trip is over.

A few months ago, wishing to experiment, I bought a cheap $10 pair of these yellow night driving glasses at a local CVS, and have been using them while driving at night.  Observations:

- The glasses certainly don't help me see *more*, that is, I can't see any more detail with them than without.  It's not like those before/after pictures used to sell the glasses.
- The glasses' yellow tinting appears mild, so that at first it seems like it should have no effect.  To the degree that the shading blocks light, there's not a noticeable loss of detail or light, excepting the yellow tint which one soon gets used to -- perhaps since less light gets in, the irises dilate more to compensate.
- No improvement in reducing [disability glare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glare_(vision)#Discomfort_and_disability).  Oncoming headlights still make it it just about as hard to see things.
- Large improvement in reducing [discomfort glare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glare_(vision)#Discomfort_and_disability).  Oncoming headlights do not hurt or cause the same stress with the glasses on.  It's rather like the difference between looking up at the sun, (which hurts), and looking at a photograph of the sun with some surrounding landscape -- in the photo there's still all the glare, but it doesn't hurt to look at the photo.
- Immediately after the oncoming headlights are gone I can see fine with both eyes, *without* an adjustment period -- that is, there's none of the loss of night vision that occurs without the glasses.
- So the squint method isn't necessary with the glasses, and both eyes stay open.
- When the trip is done, it's a mild relief to stop.  The night driving experience is very noticeably less of an ordeal.

Summing up: with respect only to vision -- the glasses don't make it easier to see when there hasn't been any glare; nor during periods of glare, but right *after* being exposed to glare the glasses make a positive difference.   With respect to pain and stress, the glasses make night driving less painful and less stressful.  Whether wearers of these glasses are not [*obliviously* driving more recklessly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_compensation) with the glasses on, (like confident [Mr. Magoo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8GTHXTEvIc)s...), seems less obvious, perhaps another answer can turn up a more general overview.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience with this type of glasses, but that's really not the type of answer that is suitable for this site. Perhaps you may want to have a look at [this FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/) to see what makes an answer good on skeptics.SE.

Comment: @Schmuddi, Thanks for the guidance... I appreciate that anecdotes, narratives and testimonials are generally the opposite of the preferred form of answer here, but the above is too long for a comment, and may help to clarify *some* of the issues with these glasses.  I worry that without such clarification, answers may over focus on fragments of the problem, and neglect to distinguish between the "good light" that drivers require to see, and the "bad light" (glare) that increases the likelihood of collisions.  The glasses necessarily reduce *both*, and answers should focus on that trade-off.

Answer (score 7):

There is some fairly old research suggesting that night-driving glasses, i.e. glasses with tinted glass, do not make it easier to see at night, and might even have a detrimental effect. Both acuity and contrast appear to be impaired (note: with the exception of the first paper by Lauer et al. 1949, I'm going by the online summaries, as I currently don't have access to the full-text publications).

[Lauer et al. (1949)](https://scholarworks.uni.edu/pias/vol56/iss1/37/) find that despite subjective preferences for this type of glasses,

> filtering lens reduces acuity in low-level illumination

and warn that

> [s]ince evidence from various sources indicates that night driving is more hazardous because of insufficient illumination, anything which further reduces seeing efficiency is not to be recommended in the present state of knowledge.

Similarly [Richards (1953)](https://trid.trb.org/view/113228) also finds that night vision does not improve by wearing yellow glasses. On the contrary,

> A small but statistically significant loss of vision occurs from yellow glasses. [...] No observers showed any consistent gain in seeing with yellow glasses for both acuity and contrast for all luminances tested, although random small gains were common.

Concluding, he also advises against using them:

> the loss from yellow glasses is potentially dangerous and the data recommend that yellow glasses not be worn during night driving on public roads.

Apparently, the detrimental effect is not restricted to yellow-tinted glasses. [Miles (1954)](https://trid.trb.org/view/107732) argues that

> the use of tinted glass in automobiles is dangerous because of decreased visual efficiency at night. Under night-driving conditions the visual acuity is 20/32 on Snellen type through colorless. Light-yellow night-driving glasses change this to 20/34. The second shade of pink glass reduces visual acuity to 20/40, while while the green windshield glass reduces it further to 20/46.

**To answer your question**: I couldn't find empirical evidence that night-time driving glasses  make it easier to see at night. On the contrary, the research that I could find suggests that wearing these types of glasses makes it **more difficult** to see at night.

Comment: A few points...  These citations are from the 1940s and '50s, when auto lighting was a bit less amok.  Reading *Lauer*, it's useful as far as it goes, but the naive design of the lab experiment fails to simulate the actual conditions of night *driving*, where lighting conditions are in constant flux, and where what Lauer calls "hot spots" often reach the eyes of a passing driver.

Comment: i remember papers from the 80s, saying the same thing about 'shooting' glasses. yellow tint was supposed to facilitate processing by a type of neuron that is slightly faster, facilitating fast reactions, thus being great for ' combat' shooting. theory was sound, but the decrease in overall light was more detrimental than the whole thing was worth.